Looking for a simple proof of this statement about angle bisectors
Theorem: Two angle bisectors make angles with the sides opposite to the internal angles they bisect. If we construct angle bisectors from two formed angles which are opposite to the same side of the triangle, then they are always going to intersect at an angle that is less than 45 degrees by the quarter of the third angle of the triangle.
The Proof:

First, we find $\alpha + \beta$: \begin{align*}
2\alpha + 2\beta &= 180^\circ - a \\ 2(\alpha+\beta)&=180^\circ-a \\ \alpha+\beta &= 90^\circ - \frac{a}{2}\end{align*}

From two pairs of 'bowtie triangles', we get the equalities: \begin{cases}\beta+\delta = \phi + x \\ \alpha+\phi = \delta + x\end{cases}

Summing them up, we get: \begin{align*}\alpha+\phi+\beta+\delta &= \delta + x + \phi + x \\ \alpha+\beta &= 2x \\ x &= \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2} \\ x &= \frac{90^\circ - a/2}{2} \\ x &= 45^\circ - \frac{a}{4}\end{align*}


Hence proven.
I know how to prove this the long way by using sum of angles in a triangle, but perhaps there is an easier elementary proof to that than this long process. Can you formulate it? Thanks.
Below goes the drawing.


Please include the "long way" you know. For one thing, it'll give readers an idea of what you consider "long". But also, it'll help readers avoid duplicating your effort, and it could help them see where steps could be shaved-off of the process. (Add the proof to the body of the question. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.) Good luck!

Can you get 4x and a in opposing angles of a cyclic quadrilateral?

@RobinSparrow I think for this statement, using quadrilaterals seems kind of an overkill.

This is a bit quicker.
Use the same relation of $2\alpha, 2\beta, a$ on the triangles with angles $2\alpha, 2\phi, \beta$ and $2\beta, 2\delta, \alpha$ to get
$$\alpha+\phi = 90^\circ - \frac{\beta}{2}$$
$$\beta+\delta = 90^\circ - \frac{\alpha}{2}$$
so that
$$\alpha+\beta+\phi+\delta = 180^\circ - \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$$
$$\alpha+\beta+\phi+\delta = 135^\circ + \frac{a}{4}$$
As $x, \alpha,\beta,\phi,\delta$ are the internal angles of a pentagram, they sum to $180^\circ$, so $x=45^\circ-\frac{a}{4}$.

Also. if we connect the vertices at the angles $2\phi$ and $2\delta$, we get a quadrilateral with inner angles $3\alpha+3\beta+2\phi+2\delta=360^\circ$, so that
$$2\alpha+2\beta+2\phi+2\delta=270^\circ+\frac{a}{2}$$


Considering the figure we have:
$\widehat{BDC}=90^o+\frac{\widehat{BAC}=a}2$
In quadrilateral FDJI we have:
$\widehat{FIJ}=180-(\widehat{FDJ}=90+\frac a2)=90-\frac a2$
I is on perpendicular bisector of JE, so we have:
$\widehat{LEM}=\widehat{IEJ}=\widehat{IJE}=\frac{\widehat{FIJ}}2=45-\frac a4$
